# Yo : Migrate from 1.0 RC to 1.0

Tags: yeoman

I had created a angular app using yo 1.0 RC

so is there any improvements in the workflow(grunt files,etc) in yo 1.0 ?

Is there anything like i can update my app(build with 1.0rc) to 1.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RC means release candidate. Before releasing a major version release candidates serve the purpose of finding and fixing bugs. No new features are added in RCs.

To see what exactly has changed have a look at the [commit log](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/commits/master). Yo doesn't have a changelog unfortunately. Most of the fixes revolve around the fact that yo recently switched from colors.js to chalk, but there were still lingering references to the old library.

So, no there's no benefit for an existing project.

As for generator-angular, here's the [changelog](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Have a look and decide for yourself.